# Container killed on request, while running mapred jobs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, cloudera, hadoop2

I am running benchmark tearasort program, mapper phase is going well. But when it comes to reducer phase i am getting below info. Ultimately job is failing

```
16/05/20 14:42:53 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1463557283514_0017_r_000008_1, Status : FAILED

Container [pid=54068,containerID=container_1463557283514_0017_01_018425] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 4.2 GB of 4 GB physical memory used; 8.1 GB of 8.4 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.

Dump of the process-tree for container_1463557283514_0017_01_018425 :
        |- PID PPID PGRPID SESSID CMD_NAME USER_MODE_TIME(MILLIS) SYSTEM_TIME(MILLIS) VMEM_USAGE(BYTES) RSSMEM_USAGE(PAGES) FULL_CMD_LINE
        |- 54068 54066 54068 54068 (bash) 0 0 115843072 362 /bin/bash -c /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_60/bin/java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN  -Xmx6144m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/u10/yarn/nm/usercache/username/appcache/application_1463557283514_0017/container_1463557283514_0017_01_018425/tmp -Dlog4j.configuration=container-log4j.properties -Dyarn.app.container.log.dir=/u04/yarn/container-logs/application_1463557283514_0017/container_1463557283514_0017_01_018425 -Dyarn.app.container.log.filesize=0 -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,CLA org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild 1x.4x.3x.9x 47528 attempt_1463557283514_0017_r_000008_1 18425 1>/u04/yarn/container-logs/application_1463557283514_0017/container_1463557283514_0017_01_018425/stdout 2>/u04/yarn/container-logs/application_1463557283514_0017/container_1463557283514_0017_01_018425/stderr
        |- 54073 54068 54068 54068 (java) 5355 6080 8573480960 1103372 /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_60/bin/java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN -Xmx6144m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/u10/yarn/nm/usercache/username/appcache/application_1463557283514_0017/container_1463557283514_0017_01_018425/tmp -Dlog4j.configuration=container-log4j.properties -Dyarn.app.container.log.dir=/u04/yarn/container-logs/application_1463557283514_0017/container_1463557283514_0017_01_018425 -Dyarn.app.container.log.filesize=0 -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,CLA org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild 1x.4x.3x.9x 47528 attempt_1463557283514_0017_r_000008_1 18425

Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
```

[image]

Comment: Container does not have enough memory. If physical machine had more than 4G RAM, increase memory for Reduce task accordingly .

Comment: My physical machine having 64 GB RAM, i have set `mapreduce_map_memory_mb=4GB` and `mapreduce_reduce_memory_mb=4GB`

Comment: Increase reducer memory to 6g and try

Comment: I have changed the values, still i am getting same `16/05/20 16:35:55 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1463557283514_0018_r_000003_1, Status : FAILED
Container [pid=46622,containerID=container_1463557283514_0018_01_018594] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 5.0 GB of 5 GB physical memory used; 8.1 GB of 10.5 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
Dump of the process-tree for container_1463557283514_0018_01_018594`

Comment: can you increase number of Reducers and further increase memory to 8g?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by doing below

Previously whatever i do, if i increase map, reducer, resource manager and container memories its using more than what i configured. Then finally i changed to cloudera default java. I was using 1.8.0_60. I have set this explicitly inside Manager. So when i changed this parameter as well as other changed parameters to CM default settings, it started working

Comment: can you provide screen shot of your changes?

Comment: I changed these parameters `mapreduce_map_memory_mb 2GB` `mapreduce_map_java_opts -Xmx1800M`
`mapreduce.reduce.java.opts -Xmx6144m`
`mapreduce_reduce_memory_mb 4 GB` `mapreduce.task.timeout 10`. But none of those worked for me. Again i changed to default icluding JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by adding the below properties in yarn-site.xml

```
<property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
   <value>false</value>
   <description>Whether virtual memory limits will be enforced for containers</description>
</property>
<property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio</name>
   <value>4</value>
   <description>Ratio between virtual memory to physical memory when setting memory limits for containers</description>
</property>
```

After adding restart all the hadoop daemons.